# Combining Sift descriptors of 5 images

Tags: sift, descriptor, object-recognition

I want to combine the descriptors of 5 images of the same object into a single descriptor file, so that I can recognize the object in any of the views of the reference images. I need to eliminate repetition of similar descriptors from getting saved from the 5 images. All I need is a set of non-repeated, unique descriptors of the object in all the 5 views. How can I get it?

Comment: Are you choosing to ignore location ([x,y]) information?